# Angular: store and display webpush messages

Tags: angular, service-worker, angular-service-worker

By default the Angular ServiceWorker displayes received PushNotifications as system notifications. I guess it could be possible to store them in localStorage too, so I can display them in my application. But how to easily implement this?